# Dynamically handle string and array in code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Datatype of stack id either can be an array or a string.

In the below code `stack[0].id` is `Array` and `stack[1].id` is string.

Issue is stackConfig is undefined when id is returned as array.

How do i handle this dynamically?

```
let stack = [{id:['stack1','stack2']},{id:'stack2'}]
let stackConfig = this.stackConfigs.find(c => c.id === selectionId);
```

Comment: What is `stackConfigs` ?

Comment: stackConfig is an object

Comment: Just check if `typeof c.id === 'string'` to distinguish between the cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
let stack = [{id:['stack1','stack3']},{id:'stack2'},{id:'stack4'}]
let selectionId = 'stack2';
let stackConfig = stack.find(c => { 
  if(Array.isArray(c.id)) { if (c.id.indexOf(selectionId) != -1) return true;}
  else { return c.id === selectionId }
  return false;
});
console.log(stackConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is check whether `c.id === selectionId` is true at any point. This might never be true, hence why it is undefined.

You could try to handle having the `selectionId` also undefined as follows:

```
if (c.id.indexOf(selectionId) != -1) return true;
```